# Vertical alignment of the top line in \sqrt

Tags: math-mode, symbols

When using \sqrt, the top line of the square root symbol seems to be closer to the enclosed text for some text than for others.  It even seems to line up differently with the left "check mark" portion of the symbol.  It seems to have something to do with the dip down of the y below the baseline of the text.  You can see the difference in the following, which I'm compiling with xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath} same problem without amsmath
\begin{document}

$\sqrt[3]{918y}$
$\sqrt{34}$
$\sqrt{34y}$
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]
Is there any way to fix it so that this doesn't happen, and \sqrt compensates for the different baselines?

Comment: The accepted answer in the link from @Qrrbrbirlbel does indeed deal with this, to summarise, it's the descender on the `y` that does it.

Comment: That does indeed answer my question.